# "Content is not allowed in Prolog" when editing style.xml

Tags: android

I was editing the style.xml

When I saved it, this error appeared:

> Content is not allowed in Prolog

I know this question has already been asked.
But the solution there didn't work.

This is my style.xml file:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <The error occur here>
<resources>
<style name="apptheme" parent="@android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an opening "<"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
    <style name="apptheme" parent="@android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You need to add "`<`" before "`?`" right at the start of the file.